# How do I handle an error from an ls command on a sftp outbound gateway in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using the following code to get a list of files that I will later retrieve from an sftp server. I added this code to try to handle an exception that happend in the sftp outbound gateway when the ls command is executed with a a directory in the payload that does not exists on the server.

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="inbound" command="ls" expression="payload"
        reply-channel="checkForNoFilesFound">
        <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
                <property name="recoveryCallback">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                        <constructor-arg ref="logger" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>        
    </int-sftp:outbound-gateway>
```

After adding that code I get the following exception. Upon an exception in the sftp gateway above, how can reroute the exception to another channel ?

```
2014-07-03 11:14:01.401  WARN 16612 --- [pool-1-thread-1] ProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway : failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive

org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway#0', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:152)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:315)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:204)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:277)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.lsGetAndArchiveFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.pearson.aimsweb.abi.SftpService.getABIFilesFromTheSFTPServer(SftpService.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

2014-07-03 11:14:01.401 ERROR 16612 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway#0', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:152)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:315)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:204)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:277)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.lsGetAndArchiveFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.pearson.aimsweb.abi.SftpService.getABIFilesFromTheSFTPServer(SftpService.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [`<request-handler-advice-chain>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) with `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

However to go ahead with answer there is need to know what you are going to do with that exception, how you want to treat it to continue the flow.

Comment: Well, just try to study that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and come back, if you'll still have some issues or questions.

Comment: I tried a request handler advice chain, how can I route the exception captured to another channel ?

Comment: The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` has `failureChannel` property. It's enough to send the exception to some another channel. Bear in mind: there is another option, which might be interested for you - `trapException = true`